# What's the difference between RegSetKeyValue and RegSetValueEx?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to set a registry value in my C++ code and I wonder what's the best way to do so. There are two different functions in the Microsoft documentation. What's the difference between both functions?

- [RegSetKeyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetkeyvaluew)
- [RegSetValueEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexw)

The only difference I see is the datatype of the `lpData` parameter. The data that the registry value is supposed to hold is passed to that parameter. It is defined like this:

- `LPCVOID lpData` in the **RegSetKeyValue** function
- `const BYTE *lpData` in the **RegSetValueEx** function

But what's the difference between both variants? The pointer you pass is the same. The type of data and its size is defined using different parameters. Therefor both functions have these two parameters: `DWORD dwType, DWORD cbData`.

Are there any use cases in which one of the two functions is favorable?

Is there a difference under the hood of both functions?

Comment: They're considerably different. The former lets you specify a root hive, then drive a full key path as text for the second argument, then specify the value name, type, contents, and size. The latter requires you open the key path all the way to the value storage location prior to invoke. Short version: the first is *much* easier to use.

Comment: I noticed that but I thought in result it's the same. But I see that it's easier to use although it doesn't make a difference in my case. I already have a handle to an open registry key at that point. Does the first one open the registry key by itself then? Does it therefore consume more performance and it's better to use the second when I already have opened the key? What does "open a registry key" even mean? The documentation of `RegOpenKeyEx` says it opens a key. It doesn't describe what that means.

Comment: Opening a registry key gives you an opaque handle to that key, which I imagine internally is a pointer to some lower branch of a tree structure. I imagine `RegSetKeyValue` is most likely a wrapper which calls `RegOpenKeyEx` for you, sets the data and then closes the handle, but even if it's not implemented that way, it must surely be more efficient if you already have a handle to the key you want to manipulate to use that rather than have to navigate the entire tree every time.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Still I wonder what "opening" and "closing" a handle means? A handle is an abstract reference to a resource. So does "open a handle" just mean "hand that reference to me"? Why do I need to close a handle? What does that do?

Comment: Closing is useful because when the reference count reaches zero, the system can unload the resource. Quote from [documentation of `CloseHandle`](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle): _In general, `CloseHandle` invalidates the specified object handle, decrements the object's handle count, and performs object retention checks. After the last handle to an object is closed, the object is removed from the system._ Also, note: _Do not use the `CloseHandle` function to close a handle to an open registry key. Instead, use the `RegCloseKey` function._